# AZURE_FUNCTIONS_ENVIRONMENT vs ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-functions

In azure functions (v2, c#), there are two environment variables that can be potentially used to identify the name of the current environment.

- `AZURE_FUNCTIONS_ENVIRONMENT`
- `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`

I am planning to use `AZURE_FUNCTIONS_ENVIRONMENT`, and I am wondering if there are reasons to choose one over another?

In terms of behavior of the two, this is what I discovered:

- `AZURE_FUNCTIONS_ENVIRONMENT` is set to `Development` locally by the functions host/runtime. It is not automatically set in azure to `Production`. One can set this in App Settings in azure.
- `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` is not set by the functions host/runtime either locally or in Azure.

I have also raised a [github issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4491) about this a couple of weeks ago, but got no response. I am hoping I might get an answer here.

Comment: Answered on GitHub.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Adding the [official answer from github issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4491#issuecomment-500966160) here for everyone's benefit:

> You'll want to use `AZURE_FUNCTIONS_ENVIRONMENT`. The Functions
>   runtime that powers a Function app on Azure is the WebHost project in
>   this repo. As the host is initializing, it looks for the
>   `AZURE_FUNCTIONS_ENVIRONMENT` app setting (as
>   `EnvironmentSettingNames.EnvironmentNameKey`) and [passes it to the
>   IWebHostBuilder](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/blob/bb15fba262572a9af1aff7f57edfaeb0f9f9b9de/src/WebJobs.Script.WebHost/Program.cs#L43).
>   Using only `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` can lead to desired behavior
>   changes and telemetry being missed.

Comment: Be aware that there are some quirks with this. See https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/6239 more more info

Answer (score 1):

`ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` is the default environment-variable to determine the environment for `IHostingEnvironment`. `IHostingEnvironment` has current two implementations. One can be found [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/tree/master/src/Hosting/Hosting) and is only supposed to be used internally. The other can be found [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Hosting/Hosting/src/Internal/HostingEnvironment.cs).

The exact idea on why there is `AZURE_FUNCTIONS_ENVIRONMENT` I cannot tell. I would suggest you to stick to `IHostingEnvironment` for ASP.NET Core applications. The version of `IHostingEnvironment` will be replaced with `IWebHostEnvironment` in the future. With the release of 3.0 they will continue to support both until the remove it. It will be marked as obsolete.

In your functions you can always set custom [variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sandbox/functions-recipes/environment-variables?tabs=csharp) and just access them via `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MY-VAR")`.